# VB.NET LINQ query on List(Of Object)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am having trouble with a LINQ query -

```
 Dim otherRecords As List(Of Objects) = listOf.Where(Function(x) x.ID_NUM = newID _
                                        And (x.Codes.Contains(ddlPrimaryCode.SelectedItem.Text.Trim) And Not x.Codes = Nothing)).ToList()
```

**Error** An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CI.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The problem is the **listOf** contains the value "Nothing" for the x.Codes.Contains.

Before I had

```
 Dim otherRecords As List(Of Objects) = listOf.Where(Function(x) x.ID_NUM = newID _
                                                       And (x.Codes.Contains(ddlPrimaryCode.SelectedItem.Text.Trim)).ToList()
```

And it was crapping out.

I need to be able to return only records with matching ID_NUM and Codes.

Comment: read what it means. do you know what a NullReferenceException means? it means that you are trying to use an object that is not initialised/instantiated....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check if it's `Nothing` first and use the [`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) keyword to stop it from evaluating the latter statement.  `AndAlso` is short-circuiting.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) for more information on what that means.

Also, when checking if an object is null, you should use the `Is` or `IsNot` operator rather than `=`.  From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx):

> When checking whether a reference (or nullable value type) variable is null, do not use = Nothing or <> Nothing. Always use Is Nothing or IsNot Nothing.

This should work

```
Dim otherRecords As List(Of Objects) = listOf.Where(Function(x) _
                                                        (x.ID_NUM = newID) AndAlso _
                                                        (x.Codes IsNot Nothing) AndAlso _
                                                        (x.Codes.Contains(ddlPrimaryCode.SelectedItem.Text.Trim()))).ToList()
```

Comment: Steven you are 100% right, I was just schooled on it from my co-worker... Thank you.